Flex и position: sticky, почему не работает?
Всем привет. Тут подобные вопросы уже видел, но все варианты проверил, но так и не понял что у меня не так.
В общем - опять почему не работает во flex'е position: sticky.
Наверно, проще по сайту будет определить (иначе много кода вставлять придётся):
https://sssr1.ru (не реклама и ничего такого, вообще домен как тестовый на данный момент).
Левый сайд бар. Нужно, чтобы он при прокрутке потом низом прилипал к низу экрана.
К верху все липнет и все работает, а к низу нет. В чем может быть проблема?
Все варианты из интернета перепробовал.

Потому что у .aaa высота 100%, т.е. во всю высоту .sidebar_left из-за чего и ему двигаться некуда.

@De.Minov я в своих девтулзах не вижу никакого 100%

@andreymal, извините, есть косяк. Пока тестил сменил на top: 0, а после вашего комментария перечитал и проблема вообще в другом.

добавь в вопрос [mcve] со своей разметкой и стилями, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку
